# Adding 2 Matrices in java

Tags: java

So I was tasked to write a program that can create two matrices and then add them both together.  I must ask the length and height of matrix 1, and then ask the length and height of matrix 2.  Which I did here:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length1, height1, length2, height2; 
    System.out.println("Welcome to the matrix adder program");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the first matrix");     
    length1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the height of the first matrix");
    height1 = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the second matrix");
    length2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the height of the second matrix");
    height2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[][] a = new int[length1][height2];
    int[][] b = new int[length2][height2];
```

Then I need to enter a value for matrix 1 row 1, column 1, row 1, column 2, and so on until it meets the dimensions of the array.  So I put

```
for (int i = 1; i < length1 + 1; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < height1 + 1; ++j) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a value for matrix 1 space "+ i + "," + j);
            a[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

And this is where I get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at MaxtrixAddition.main(MaxtrixAddition.java:32)

It would need to output something like this:

```
Please enter a value for matrix 1 space 1, 1
4
Please enter a value for matrix 1 space 1, 2
1
Please enter a value for matrix 1 space 2, 1
8
Please enter a value for matrix 1 space 2, 2
7

Please enter a value for matrix 2 space 1, 1
1
Please enter a value for matrix 2 space 1, 2
3
Please enter a value for matrix 2 space 2, 1
2
Please enter a value for matrix 2 space 2, 2
4
```

What would I need to do to get rid of that error?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood what you want to do.

Arrays start at position 0.

So your code snip should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length1; ++i) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height1 ; ++j) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value for matrix 1 space "+ i + "," + j);
        a[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing that would give me "Please enter a value for matrix 1 space 0, 0."  When I want it to say 1,1. @tstark81

Comment: I fixed it by doing this                                                                                           int[][] a = new int[length1+1][height2+1];
int[][] b = new int[length2+1][height2+1];

Comment: You can just replace the System.out.println line to System.out.println("Please enter a value for matrix 1 space "+ (i+1) + "," + (j+1));

Comment: Doing what you posted on that suggestion is still wrong. You are going to have an array with a dimension different from the one the input requested. Where you just ignore the first line and the first column entirely.

Comment: Thank you for that part.  What you did helped a lot.  Now just one more thing.  If I wanted to add them together I would need to make an    `int[][] c = new int[][]`;  How would I go about putting length1, length 2, height 1, and height 2   Would I just do `nt[][] c = new int[lenght1 + length2][height1 + height2]`  ?  @tstark81

Comment: Do you mean put them all in a single matrix, merging the matrix a and b? If so: int[][] c = new[length1 + length2][height1 + height2].

Comment: Meant to say how would I go about getting the same dimensions as a and b for c ?  @tstark81

Comment: Well I assigned length1 and height1 from matrix 1 to c.  Am I allowed to do that or should I do another variable. `int[][] c = new int[length1][height1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the two matrices is");
        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++) {
                System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }`

Comment: Oh, so you don't want to merge the matrices, you want to add it's contents. The problem with that is that you allow to have a and b with different dimensions. If they were the same dimension, your code would work.

Comment: Sorry, I never posted this in the original part but I had the code in there `if ((height1 != height2) || length1 != length2)) {
            System.out.println("Cannot add these! Dimension mismatch");
            return;
        }`